# Convert RFC 822 timestamp to unixtime, timezone values not working , C/C++

Tags: c++, c, timestamp, unix-timestamp, rfc822

I've a function which converts an RFC 822 timestamp to unixtime

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {

struct tm tm;
time_t unixtime;

strptime("Sun, 20 Feb 2011 10:28:02 +0800","%a, %e %h %Y %H:%M:%S %z",&tm);

unixtime = mktime(&tm);
printf("%d\n",unixtime);

return 0;
}
```

Problem: The timezone part (%z) doesn't seem to be working. I tried changing input timezone to other values +0100, + 0200 ect without changing other date values, it always gives the same unixtime stamp (ie, unixtimestamp corresponding to GMT)

What can be the issue here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

struct tm does not contain a timezone field. %z is supported simply to support the same flags as strftime. You'll need to extract and adjust the timezone offset manually.

Comment: Well, the man page for strptime says it supports %z via GNU extensions. check at the bottom of the page: http://linux.die.net/man/3/strptime

Comment: Yes, it supports *parsing of* these. That doesn't give struct tm a timezone member though. The man page (at least on my closest linux box) explicitly states "In most cases the corresponding fields are parsed, but no field in tm is changed."

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'll manually parse the timezone string and offset the required number of seconds.